How much oxalic acid is carried with the product gases during its thermal decomposition at 230°C?
I’d like to measure the amount of oxalic acid carried with the product gases during its thermal decomposition at 230°C. It takes 120 seconds to decompose 2.5 g in an electrically heated crucible (PID).
I know that H₂O, CO, and CO₂ are produced; however, in real-world conditions, the process is not ideal, and the product gases are mixed with some sublimated oxalic acid.
Is it possible to measure this using a simple technique (at home), or is gas chromatography required?
